# Convert string to nested json objects with C#

Tags: c#

I have some strings like:

```
Season1.SubSeason.Code1.Sector
Season1.SubSeason.Code1.Name
Season1.SubSeason.Code2.Sector
Season1.SubSeason.Code1.Name
Season1.Price
Data_Input.Setup
Data_Reprice.Value
```

and want to convert to:

```
{
    Season1 : {
       SubSeason : {
         Code1 : {
            Sector: "",
            Name: ""
         },
         Code2 : {
            Sector: "",
            Name: ""
         }
       },
       Price: 10
    },
    Data_Input: {
       Setup: ""
    },
    Data_Reprice: {
       Value: 10111
    }
}
```

What I tried so far:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach(var item in array) {
   var split = item.Split('.');
   var key = split[0];
   if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
   {
      dict[key] = new Dictionary<string, object>();    
   } else {
     foreach (var spl in split.Skip(1)) {
        if (dict[key] != null && dict[key] is Dictionary<string, object> ad) {
           if (!ad.ContainsKey(spl))
           {
                ad[spl] = new Dictionary<string, object>();      
           } else {
                var o = ad[spl] as Dictionary<string, object>;
                if (!o.ContainsKey(spl))
                {
                    o[spl] = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                }
           }
        }
     }
   }
}

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.Indented);
```

but it outputs like:

```
{
  "Season1": {
    "SubSeason": {
      "SubSeason": {}
    },
    "Code1": {
      "Code1": {}
    },
    "Name": {
      "Name": {}
    },
    "Code2": {},
    "Sector": {},
    "Price": {}
  },
  "Data_Input": {},
  "Data_Reprice": {}
}
```

How can solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert these strings into nested JSON objects using C#, you'd first need to parse these strings and organize them in a nested fashion, then serialize them into JSON.

Let's break down the steps:

Split each string by the `.` character.
Use the resulting string array to create a nested dictionary (or use an existing dictionary to update it).
Serialize the dictionary into a JSON format.
Here's an example C# code that accomplishes this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> inputStrings = new List<string>
        {
            "Season1.SubSeason.Code1.Sector",
            "Season1.SubSeason.Code1.Name",
            "Season1.SubSeason.Code2.Sector",
            "Season1.SubSeason.Code1.Name",
            "Season1.Price",
            "Data_Input.Setup",
            "Data_Reprice.Value"
        };

        Dictionary<string, object> root = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (var str in inputStrings)
        {
            AddToDictionary(root, str.Split('.'));
        }

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

    private static void AddToDictionary(Dictionary<string, object> dict, string[] parts)
    {
        if (parts.Length == 1)
        {
            dict[parts[0]] = null;
            return;
        }

        if (!dict.ContainsKey(parts[0]))
        {
            dict[parts[0]] = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        AddToDictionary((Dictionary<string, object>)dict[parts[0]], parts[1..]);
    }
}
```

Please note that this code uses the `Newtonsoft.Json` library to serialize the dictionary to JSON format. You'd need to install this library, which can be done via NuGet package manager with:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

The generated JSON will have `null` values for the leaf nodes, but the structure will represent the nested path of your string inputs. If you'd like to assign some other default value instead of `null` for the leaf nodes, you can modify the code accordingly.